# Environment Variable is overriden with Spring Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I set my oracle environment variable property in a property file as follows:

```
oracle.home=XXX
file.path=C:\workspace
```

I am using spring factory bean annotation and I declare oracle Home as follows in a class:

```
@Value("${oracle.home}") private String oracleHome; //becomes YYY
```

All my other property are read in correctly, but the `oracleHome` is  overriden with what I have set in my environment (e.g. ORACLE_HOME) and not read in from property file..

Why does this happen and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't understand. You have a properties file loaded with `oracle.home` and you also have a system property called `oracle.home`?

Comment: application reads in the ORACLE_HOME system env instead of what I set in property file. I have two versions of oracle home.

Comment: I don't know how `ORACLE_HOME` translates to `oracle.home`. Spring can have multiple property sources. These are ordered. I believe system properties and environment properties are ordered first. Your custom `.properties` files are ordered after that. There should be a way to be explicit in the order.

Comment: how is your property place holder is configured?

Answer (score 1):

OS environment variables are considered in higher order than .properties file. 
Most operating systems disallow period-separated key names, so spring automatically map your proprety name from ORACLE_HOME to oracle.home. You can read more here:

[Properties considering order](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can control your property place holder never to check system properties and override with the key/value you have in properties file.

there are 3 values available

- SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK  - Check system properties if not
  resolvable in the specified properties.
- SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_NEVER  - Never check system properties.
- SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE - Check system properties first, before
  trying the specified properties.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties">
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
    <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_NEVER</value>
</property>
</context>
```

or

```
       @Bean
       public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
          PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
          p.setLocation("..")
          p.setSystemPropertiesMode(SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_NEVER);
          return p;
       }
```